# Strange behaviour of shaperenderer in libGDX

Tags: opengl, libgdx

For some background information, I was working on a lighting system with shadows. I ran into a problem trying to add the dark, transparent color to the buffer. You'll see that I am rendering shapes with the function renderOccluders(sr) in the buffer. (sr is my ShapeRenderer.) This should result in **adding** a transparent layer of black to the FBO. Instead of doing this it **sets** a transparent layer of black color. However, a very strange thing is that when I move the lines of code for drawing the shape to after the buffer ends the code does work. Seemingly using the shaperenderer in a buffer results differently than using it outside a buffer.

Here is my code:

```
    cam.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    sr.setProjectionMatrix(batch.getProjectionMatrix());

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,0,0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    buffer.begin(); // Reason for buffer is that blending here is only meant for darkness and light

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //renderDarkness();

    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(770,771);
    sr.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    sr.setColor(0,0,0,.5f);

    for (Light light : crtLvl.lights) { light.renderOccluders(sr);}

    sr.end();
    Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);

    buffer.end();

    sprite_darknessOverlay = new Sprite(buffer.getColorBufferTexture());
    sprite_darknessOverlay.flip(false, true);
    sprite_darknessOverlay.setSize(newWidth,newHeight);
    sprite_darknessOverlay.setPosition(cam.position.x - newWidth / 2, cam.position.y - newHeight / 2);
    sprite_darknessOverlay.setColor(1,1,1,1);
    batch.begin();

    sprite_darknessOverlay.draw(batch);

    batch.end();
```

I want to render shapes inside the buffer like it should. Does someone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

When drawing to a buffer, keep in mind that the alpha part of the blend equation suddenly becomes important because it will later be used to draw the buffer to the screen. Usually the alpha part of the equation doesn't matter because the final alpha of the back buffer is not used for anything. Since it usually doesn't matter, you usually can simply use blendFunc instead of blendFuncSeparate.

Without knowing far more detail about how you're doing your lighting, I'll just suggest that you use a clear color with alpha 1, and when drawing to the frame buffer, use `batch.setBlendFuncSeparate()` and set the alpha parameters to GL_ONE, GL_ZERO. Then when drawing the frame buffer's image to the screen, set its color's alpha to the amount of transparency you want. This is probably wrong for what you are specifically trying to do, but should get you started.